# Cannot return Null from a non-nullable type function

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the error message I am getting:

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

on the following code:

```
Product findProductById(String prodId) {
  _productsList.firstWhere((element) {
    return prodId == element.id;
  });
}
```

I want to find the Product by its id but if its not found what should I return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not `return`ing inside the `findProductById` function:

```dart
Product findProductById(String prodId) {
  return _productsList.firstWhere((element) {
    return prodId == element.id;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From Dart 2.12 and up, we need to specify whether if a type is nullable or non-nullable.
In your case, you should add '?' question mark after the type name Product as you can see below, which will tell the compiler that your function can return a nullable product.
Also you forgot to return the filtered product from the productList.

```
Product? findProductById(String prodId) {
return _productsList.firstWhere((element) {
  return prodId == element.id;
});
```

Comment: but in that case assigning a value will not work. It gives error cannot assign a value of type Product? to type Product

Comment: @ManrajSingh: You should handle the null value when incorrect `prodId` is given. Hence the `Product?` is used to force you to handle it.

Comment: The [`firstWhere` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html) returns a non-nullable type, so there's no need of returning a nullable type in `findProductById`.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a empty Product it's not found.

```
  Product findProductById(String productId) {
    return productList.firstWhere((element) => element.id == productId,
        orElse: () => Product() // make a empty product using default constructor);
  }
```